# How can I reset my password in drupal7

Tags: users

I am new to Drupal and this forum.

My problem is that I want to reset my password in Drupal without logging onto my site, but I can only access user/password when I'm logged in.

I've searched a lot and haven't been able to find anything else.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you can use drush for it.

Comment: First things first - do you use Drush...

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I need to do this in my application.If the user forgot his password,then he reset his password.

Comment: already there is an option for forgot password in drupal

Answer (score 6):

If you have drush installed, you can reset your password from the command line using

```bash
drush upwd --password="givememypasswordback" admin
```

For more information you could see the [link](https://drupal.org/node/44164).

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to achieve this:

- Visit *yousite.com/user/password* then enter your email address and you'll then receive an email with a link to reset your password on your Drupal site.
- With drush, you have two different ways of doing things:

  ```
  $ drush uli --uid=1 --uri=http://yoursite.com
  ```

This command will return a URL that will allow you to log in to the site without actually knowing your admin password. Handy.

- Or as previously suggested by @Nitesh Sethia, using drush, again, to reset your admin password:

  ```
  $ drush upwd <username> --password="<newpassword>"
  ```
- Another interesting option is to use the password-hash.sh script that ships with Drupal. At the root of your Drupal codebase, type:

  ```
  $ ./scripts/password-hash.sh <newpassword>
  ```

This will return a hash with the SHA 512 security. Copy that hash, now log in to your MySQL prompt or via phpMyAdmin (or whatever other GUI of your choice). Select the "users" table and update your admin account by replacing the "pass" hash by your newly generated one. Save. Done. Assuming you'll go for the MySQL prompt and will want to reset UID 1 (superuser) password, run:

```
    mysql > UPDATE `<yourdatabase>`.`users` SET `pass` = '<yourhash>' WHERE `users`.`uid` = 1;
```

**Last option that I wouldn't recommend** is to temporarily hack your `index.php` file so that, under `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);` you add:

```
    require_once 'includes/password.inc';
    echo user_hash_password('<newpassword>');
    die();
```

Now hit the homepage, copy the hash, and update the "pass" field in the database as explained previously. Revert the changes in `index.php`. Done.